# Matrix representation composite system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

I am considering an assignment involving the Hubbard model. A state is given by $|\Phi\rangle=-|2\uparrow1\downarrow\rangle-|1\uparrow2\downarrow\rangle$ where particle 1 and 2 are electrons. The state is then written in the matrix representation $|\Phi\rangle=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix}$. I do not really know how you get to that matrix representation ? I think my problem is that I do not generally know how to go from the ket to the matrix. I know that for a spin up electron we have the matrix (1,0) and (0,1) for spin down. But for this composite systems I am not sure. \

The basis are given by the 4 states: $|1\uparrow1\downarrow\rangle$,$|2\uparrow2\downarrow\rangle$, $|1\uparrow2\downarrow\rangle$,$|1\downarrow2\uparrow\rangle$.

Comment: Can you provide more background on the problem? Do you know anything about the basis of your column vector?

Comment: I edited my question by adding the basis in the bottom.

Comment: Is your 4th basis vector correct? Seems like it should have arrows up and then down like the others.

Comment: It is written like that in the notes

Comment: I can only see this making sense if $\left|1\uparrow2\downarrow\right>=-\left|1\downarrow2\uparrow\right>$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recipe.

1. Write down your basis kets, making sure they are orthonormal.
2. Pick any ordering of these kets, but having picked it, stick to it.
3. If there are $N$ basis kets you need $N$ vectors, each with $N$ components. You simply write the $N$ vectors which have just a single element 1 and the rest zero (i.e. columns of the $N \times N$ identity matrix), and assign them one by one to represent your basis kets. One can add further mathematical argument to show why this is what you have to do, but I am skipping that.

I can't understand the list of basis kets you gave, so I will have to illustrate the method by showing what happens for the standard four states for a pair of spin half particles. I have ordered them so as to try to match the vector you quoted. Thus I get
$$
|\uparrow\uparrow\rangle \leftrightarrow
\left[ \begin{array}{c} 1\\0\\0\\0 \end{array} \right]
,\;\;
|\downarrow\downarrow\rangle
\leftrightarrow
\left[ \begin{array}{c} 0\\1\\0\\0 \end{array} \right]
$$
$$
|\downarrow\uparrow\rangle
\leftrightarrow
\left[ \begin{array}{c} 0\\0\\1\\0 \end{array} \right]
,\;\;
|\uparrow\downarrow\rangle
 \leftrightarrow
\left[ \begin{array}{c} 0\\0\\0\\1 \end{array} \right]
$$

One can also introduce an overall sign (or other phase factor), but that would be unusual. When working with a pair of spins I wouldn't normally pick the above order but as I say I tried to show something close to what seems to be going on in your example.

Comment: I get the same for the  standard fours states. But I am not sure still how to get the desired....